# How long should a garden tractor battery last?

Tags: tool-maintenance, lawn-mower

It seems like every year I'm needing to buy a new battery for my lawn tractor. A battery that worked perfectly well never seems to make it through the off-season in-tact.

Is this normal? Is there something I could do to make them last more than one season?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have a lawn tractor, but presumably this is a lead acid battery? (i.e. similar to a car battery but smaller)

If so, when stored for long periods of time, they should be hooked up to a slow charger. Power requirements are minimal: what you need is more of a float charger to avoid self-discharge. (i.e. any lead acid battery charger will do, but set it to slow or float - do not use a fast charge setting)

A discharged lead acid battery will result in sulfur build up on the electrodes (in the form of lead sulfate). This is known as **sulfation**. Pulse conditioning is said to help. Also with wet batteries (i.e. not the various gel types), you can use de-sulfurization tablets in each cell which might work.  Either way, it is better to avoid **sulfation** in the first place. So take the battery out during winter, and keep it permanently connected to a lead acid charger.

Better battery sellers will keep their lead acid battery stock on a "float charge" like this, although they may have some on display which aren't. They will either rotate them periodically, or they are relying on stock turnover to avoid discharge problems.

Comment: +1 Great answer for something that's a bit outside our normal range of questions!

Comment: Battery Tender is one of the better known brands of these types of chargers. They make them for 12v and 6v batteries. Used to use one back when I had a motorcycle.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problems, as I use my tractor all year round. My current tractor battery is over 5 years old now, and still strong. Assuming you don't plow your driveway though...

It can help to pull the battery and store it in a warmer place, rather than leaving it all winter in a cold garage. A quick charge in the spring may be necessary to bring it back to form, although I have never found it necessary. For example, our boat battery spends winters in our basement, and has always been ready to go with no charge at all.

Make sure the water is topped off, unless it is a sealed battery. (Tractor batteries seem not to be so in my experience.) Use distilled water for this purpose.

Keep your battery posts clean. Bad contacts will prevent the battery from charging, and will make it seem like you have a dud for a battery. You can buy some stuff (from an auto parts store) to paint onto the posts to inhibit corrosion.

Check the wires to and from your battery. Are they loose or frayed? If so, tighten/replace them.

When you replace the battery, get a better battery than the default stock. For a few dollars more, the extra reserve amps will help to start your engine.

Take care of your tractor. Put stabilizer in the gas if left for some time. Change the oil at least once a year, more so if you push the beast or live in a dusty area. Keep the air filer clean.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I think the alternator is getting weak, the wiring is getting old, corrosion is built up, and they are just cheap batteries.  I've had the best luck buying a new battery on sale with rebates or incentives every year or two and replacing it. Also, sell your old battery to a recycler if you get to keep it! That's a good time to polish up or replace the battery cable wires and terminals also.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine lawn mower battery use would be similar to golf caddy battery use. Golf caddy batteries usually last 3 to 5 years (lead acid batteries). Average use would be 4 hours of stop and go use per round, 3 times per week. Lithium ion batteries last significantly longer. Important to battery life is to recharge it immediately after each use; battery life is adversely affected by deep discharges.

ADE

Answer (score 0):

Mine only lasted 8 months, bought new one but this time I bought a battery maintainer a small battery charger, was told to take it inside recharge every other week or month instead of just leaving it outside